# Can gruntfile usemin function be customized?

Tags: css, gruntjs, minify

I discovered today that the grunt build <strike>cssmin</strike> usemin is stripping an attribute, "-webkit-box-sizing", causing display issues in older versions of Safari (e.g. on a G5 ppc mac). Restoring it manually fixes the display issue of the built, "dist" version. Is there a way to edit gruntfile.js to have it ignore the attribute and leave it in the minified style sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your cssmin grunt specific code and the CSS in question?

Comment: cssmin shoudn't touch your vendor prefixed properties. Are you sure it's cssmin?

Comment: Hi, See my reply to Ben's answer -- the problem is (apparently) "usemin", as "cssmin" is optional (commented out) in the default gruntfile.js I got through "yo angular" boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

What version of grunt-contrib-cssmin are you using? I am using `0.6.2` with the following configuration:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'dist/master.min.css' : 'css/master.css'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As a test:

```
body {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Is minified to this:

```
body{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
```

I'm not sure that cssmin is the problem here.

Edit: Bumped my version to the latest (`0.7.0` at time of writing) and the output is the same.

Comment: Hi, you're right, it's not "cssmin" (which I have commented out in my gruntfile.js), but "usemin" (0.1.13) doing the minifying and (presumably) causing the problem. I only realized it when I viewed the "dist" build in the old Safari whereas I had been viewing it as working all along as a 'raw' Angular app (with un-minified css). Anyway, my question now applies to modifying "usemin" to preserve the attribute. Do you know whether that's possible?

Comment: AFAIK usemin passes a configuration *to* cssmin, it doesn't know about minifying itself. If you find that usemin breaks your output you could always run cssmin before the usemin task runs, that way that task only updates the references to that file (and/or a version with an MD5 hash added to the filename).

Comment: I guess the short answer, for me at least, is 'no' (or the manual fix of each new build is vastly easier). It's been doing this consistently in the past dozen or so builds over several weeks (at least), just noticed it now and reviewed the backups. Strangely the only other -webkit instance ("-webkit-transform-origin") is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: When you're using one of the yeoman generators to generate your Gruntfile... do you at any case use autoprefixer? Autoprefixer checks vendor prefixes based on the caniuse.com support tables, box-sizing might already be in the browser generations area where the standard autoprefixer configuration doesn't care anymore.

Comment: It was generated by generator-angular 0.4.0. I'd guessed the attribute might well be deprecated, since the display issue is not manifested in newer webkit-based browsers, and wondered if that's why it was being stripped out.

Comment: Just did a check. generator-angular *uses* autoprefixer. Try to kill all autoprefixer tasks in your Gruntfile, than everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about you invert the tasks?

Instead of:

```
'autoprefixer:dist',
'cssmin',
```

You could use:

```
'cssmin',
'autoprefixer:dist',
```

IOW, minify first, then add vendor-prefixes.